# How to draw a separator line below DataGrid headers in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Is there a way to draw a separator line below the headers in a DataGrid? I have set GridLinesVisibility to None as I don't want any gridlines except the one below the headers. I'm struggling to find a way to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `DataGridColumnHeader`'s `ControlTemplate`.

I used the original `DataGrid`'s template and replaced the default border and fill with a `Rectangle` with a height of 1.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Style.Resources>

                <!-- This style is required for the column resize thumbs -->
                <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid Background="White">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

                            <Thumb Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                            <Thumb Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />

                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Black"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```